# How are pic text and options supposed to be used?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to use `pic text` but it has no effect on my code.

This is a Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{seagull/.pic={\draw (-3mm,0) to [bend left] (0,0) to [bend left] (3mm,0);}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic[pic text=test, pic text options={midway,above,red}]{seagull};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `\tikzpictext` and  `\tikzpictextoptions` where the settings will be applied:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{seagull/.pic={
    \draw (-3mm,0) to [bend left] (0,0) to [bend left] (3mm,0) node[\tikzpictextoptions]{\tikzpictext};
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic[pic text=test, pic text options=midway,above,text=red]{seagull};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Also note that  `pic text options` does not want braces and that `red` will color the seagull too, if you want to color the text only, use `text=red`.

[image]